# How to don't send the bot's username in python telegram bot switch_inline_query

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am making the inviting friend into the bot.

```
InlineKeyboardButton(' Invite Friend', switch_inline_query = 'https://t.me/xxxx?start=friend-' + str(user['id']))
```

After the click, the button and I choose the chat on my contacts.
But on a friend's chat, the bot's username is inserted. I want to send only the link.
[I want to remove this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2oIq.png)

or I want to make [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJYau.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the username of the bot from the message itself.

Altough many bots use a workaround where you are prompted with a username and a special identifier which allows the bot to prompt the InlineQuery mode and show up a button which can send any text you want

[image: Example given]

(I've found this simple bot that does this too, you can try it [here](https://t.me/TemplateBot))

Here's also an [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinebot.py) found on the official `python_telegram_bot` repo

Comment: Hi, ExalFabu. Thank you for your reply. How did you add the button on there?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinebot.py#L42) you can find a detailed example of how you could achieve it. Unfortunately I don't have any code available to share it to you.

With that example and looking up Inline Mode you should be able to figure it out.